# JS storage HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: javascript, storage

Загружаю страницу `mysite.com/1.php` по `HTTPS` с кодом:

```
window.addEventListener("storage", function(e) { alert(1); } );
```

Загружаю страницу `mysite.com/2.php` по `HTTPS` с кодом:

```
localStorage.setItem("nave", Math.random());
```

Событие alert срабатывает. Однако если `mysite.com/2.php` загрузить по `HTTP` в (чем и состоит задача) alert не срабатывает.

Вопрос, как сделать что alert срабатывал при запуске `mysite.com/2.php` загруженной по `HTTP`при том что `mysite.com/1.php` загружена по `HTTPS`?